# Haars Cascade for Actionscript development

Tags: actionscript, opencv

I have an object that I want to be able to recognize in AS3.

There's a port of OpenCV for AS3 already, that works with Haars cascades, so now I need to create a cascade of my object.

From what I've read, I'll have to create an XML of several images (positive and negative), but I can't find a program that'll do that for Mac OS X.

Is there anything I can use that'll generate that XML on Mac OS X?

Cheers,
Andre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just a parsing job. Use this: http://www.moment77.se/flash-classes/code-snippets/convert-haar-cascades-from-xml-to-actionscript/