# Use other Haarcascade xml with Marilena

Tags: actionscript, opencv, face-detection

I have used OpenCV and was able to use Face Detection, Upper Body detection etc. easily.

I have also used the Marilena project (Open CV port for Actionscript) which has the Haarcascade XML files ported into AS. This also works fine as is.

Now, what I am trying to do is - Do Upper Body detection using Actionscript. So, I want to use OpenCV's XML in Marilena - For that, the XML should be translated into Marilena's format. I was able to achieve this translation using one of the solutions that I found on [Stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957236/haars-cascade-for-actionscript-development).

However, when I copied this generated code and ran my program, the detection didn't happen as expected. It resulted in a block in some random place, a false positive. When I tried translating OpenCV's Face Detection XML to Marilena, again it failed. When I used Marilena's original code, it worked again.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nikhil, were you finally able to do this? I have similar requirement. With these cascades face detection works nicely, but all other XMLs either don't work or give false negatives?

Comment: Pradeep - Unfortunately, no, I was not able to do it :-/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Marilena uses .xml files just the same as OpenCV. Did you try running the sample they provided but replacing their .xml file with your own? I can't see anywhere where they require you to port your haar file to actionscript.

Comment: Yes, Marilena uses the same xml files as OpenCV - However, it doesn't use it in the xml format. It requires translation of the xml into the format suited for Marilena (which can be achieved using this script here - http://www.moment77.se/flash-classes/code-snippets/convert-haar-cascades-from-xml-to-actionscript/)

Comment: I don't know Japanese, so navigating the project page was a little tricky. But I noticed in their sample they were using a plain .xml file. http://www.libspark.org/browser/as3/Marilena/trunk/samples That is what I am referencing.